# WPF Datagrid DataGridColumnHeader background color not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

Into a WPF project, I set a style to a GridView's headers.

```
   <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

This worked perfectly for the concerned properties.
But for any reason, adding this style changes the background color.
CF attached screenshot, there is a color difference between the header's text background and what surrounds it.
[image]

Where does this come from?
I tried to add this to the style (F7F7F7 seems to be the correct outter color):

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#F7F7F7"/>
```

Did not help.

Relying on you guys :)

Comment: You can try setting `BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}` in case you already have some style that should cover it but is overriden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can set Background as Transparent.

   ```
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   ```
2. But for me best would be :

   ```
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   ```

Comment: Solved my issue. Thx bro.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the style to inherit from the base style so it does alter the other properties

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}>
```